# Swap over div content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that this has been asked plenty of times but after reading several threads I cannot seem to get the right combination of HTML / CSS and JS happening to get the desired effect happening for my panel and I feel that I am going around in circles.

I think I have set up the HTML correctly so that the extra divs are hidden but I think it is my CSS and JS that are the problems because I just cant get it to swap over when the li icons are clicked.

Situation:
I have a horizontal timeline that has four points which I want to act as clickable elements, and depending on what point is clicked will determine what hidden content panel is shown.

- Div 1 content shown by default
- Click on pt 2 and div 2 content shown
- Click on pt 3 and div 3 content shown
- Click on pt 4 and div 4 content shown

Also not sure how to get the timeline to be on one continuous line.  It was working fine as li but as soon as I wrapped in link it went skewif.

Any help, tips or pointers on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.. brett

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="icon">
        <img src="http://www.arteria-glh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/design-centre.png">
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
        <h3>Design Centre Content #1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-2" class="hidden">
    <div id="icon">
        <img src="http://www.arteria-glh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/design-centre.png">
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
        <h3>Design Centre Content #2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-3" class="hidden">
    <div id="icon">
        <img src="http://www.arteria-glh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/design-centre.png">
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
        <h3>Design Centre Content #3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-4" class="hidden">
    <div id="icon">
        <img src="http://www.arteria-glh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/design-centre.png">
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
        <h3>Design Centre Content #4</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ol.progtrckr {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

ol.progtrckr li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="4"] li { 
    width: 25%; 
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
    color: #414042;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #517316;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
    color: #fafafa; 
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #afdf5d;
}

ol.progtrckr li:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
    content: "◉";
    color: #afdf5d;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -0.6em;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
    content: "◉";
    color: #dff6b8;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -0.6em;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#content-2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#content-3 {
   margin-top: 50px;
   margin-left: 15%;
}

#content-4 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div#icon {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

div#copy {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #78a22f;
    size: 24px;
}

p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("div.containter ul li").each(function(){
$(this).onclick(function(){

   $("div.content").hide();

  $("div" + $(this).attr("href")).show();

});
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `each` loop, and also `onclick` should be `click`. Initial JS code should be `$("div.containter ul li").click(function(){ ....` .

Comment: For the future, [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/sfespeo1/1/) are wonderful

Comment: Ids should be unique to the whole document, don't use them like classes.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt even think to do a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/razordigital/a0g4jajg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

I have made some HTML changes. ID's are unique, there should not be any duplicate ID's.

```
$(".progtrckr a").click(function(){
    var currentDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.data').each(function(){
        if(! $(this).hasClass('hidden')){
            $(this).addClass('hidden')
        }
    });
    $(''+currentDiv+'').removeClass('hidden'); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/a0g4jajg/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this Rino... I used your demo as the basis and made some changes to accommodate content.  Works nicely now :)

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/razordigital/8ovs15dj/

Answer (score 0):

a couple of issues:

wrap your `<a>` tags inside of the `<li>` instead of the other way around. This should make the timeline a straight line again.

`<a>` tags are `display: inline` by default, so in order for them to actually show up, you need them to have text in them, otherwise, set them to `display: inline-block` or `block`

however, doing this will mess up the dots on your timeline, so you need to clean up your css so it works with this

as far as jquery goes, the click event handler is

```
$('element' or '.class' or '#id').on('click', function(){
```

here's a quick example on how to click on buttons and show corresponding data:

http://jsfiddle.net/7zm8mawh/

Comment: Thanks Abdul... I couldnt seem to get this to work properly so I used Rino's suggestion below and then hacked it to fit requirements.  Appreciate your efforts though so thanks mate :)